# Angular 2 - I need a component to output a function so that a nested component can call it

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

Angular 2 - I need a component to output a function so that a nested component can call it.

I'm using typescript and angular 2.

This is the output code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'jobs', 
  providers: [Job, JobService, Notification, NotificationService, Counties, Towns], 
  templateUrl: './app/components/job/jobs.html',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgIf, NgFor, DialogJob, BootFlatDatePicker],
  pipes:[SearchFilter],


  outputs: ['jobCancelledNotification']


})

jobCancelledNotification = (event) => {console.log("job cancelled via output!!!!"); }
```

I need "jobCancelledNotification" to be called from a nested dialog component.

For my nested dialog component I have an output:

```
   @Output() jobCancelledNotification = new EventEmitter();
```

Then I try call it with this:

```
   this.jobCancelledNotification.emit("event");
```

When the dialog component is ready is needs to call jobCancelledNotification which calls jobCancelledNotification from the parent component.

Comment: Nothing happens, I dont even get a console error or compiler error

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to include NgIf, NgFor and CORE_DIRECTIVES they are already included.

In parent component:

````
```<message (message)="call($event)"></message>```
export class App {
 response: any;
 call(message: any) {
   this.response = message;
 }
}
````

In child component:

```
@Output() message = new EventEmitter();
constructor() {
 setTimeout(()=> {
    this.message.emit("Hello from MessageCmp");
 },2000);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/vUocS8dDTKsJFGGSSKYk?p=preview

Comment: when I emit I can call that emit from another component?

Comment: All I want to achieve is for a nested component to call a method in its parent component

Comment: I improved my answer, hopefully it will help.